# Rig Veda - The demon Svarbhanu, Rahu and eclipse

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, eclipse

[This](http://utkarshspeak.blogspot.in/2010/10/mythical-explanation-of-eclipse-indian.html) blog article talks how the demonic form of *Svarbhanu* is used to explain the phenomenon of eclipse. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svarbh%C4%81nu) wiki article also says that Svarbhanu is a name used for *Rahu* in Puranas. It also claims that the first mention of Svarbhanu can be found in the Rig Veda.

What is the story of Svarbhanu as found in the *Rig Veda*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The story about Svarbhanu is found [here in English](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv05040.htm) and [here in Sanskrit](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv05040.htm) in Rig Veda, Book 5, HYMN XL.

> आ याह्य अद्रिभिः सुतं सोमं सोमपते पिब | 
>   वर्षन्न इन्द्र वर्षभिर वर्त्रहन्तम ||
>
> वर्षा गरावा वर्षा मदो वर्षा सोमो अयं सुतः | 
>   वर्षन्न इन्द्र वर्षभिर वर्त्रहन्तम ||
>
> वर्षा तवा वर्षणं हुवे वज्रिञ चित्राभिर ऊतिभिः | 
>   वर्षन्न इन्द्र वर्षभिर वर्त्रहन्तम ||
>
> रजीषी वज्री वर्षभस तुराषाट छुष्मी राजा वर्त्रहा सोमपावा | 
>   युक्त्वा हरिभ्याम उप यासद अर्वाङ माध्यंदिने सवने मत्सद इन्द्रः ||
>
> यत तवा सूर्य सवर्भानुस तमसाविध्यद आसुरः | 
>   अक्षेत्रविद यथा मुग्धो भुवनान्य अदीधयुः ||
>
> सवर्भानोर अध यद इन्द्र माया अवो दिवो वर्तमाना अवाहन | 
>   गूळ्हं सूर्यं तमसापव्रतेन तुरीयेण बरह्मणाविन्दद अत्रिः ||
>
> मा माम इमं तव सन्तम अत्र इरस्या दरुग्धो भियसा नि गारीत | 
>   तवम मित्रो असि सत्यराधास तौ मेहावतं वरुणश च राजा ||
>
> गराव्णो बरह्मा युयुजानः सपर्यन कीरिणा देवान नमसोपशिक्षन | 
>   अत्रिः सूर्यस्य दिवि चक्षुर आधात सवर्भानोर अप माया अघुक्षत ||
>
> यं वै सूर्यं सवर्भानुस तमसाविध्यद आसुरः | 
>   अत्रयस तम अन्व अविन्दन नह्य अन्ये अशक्नुवन ||

Below is the English translation:

> 1. COME thou to what the stones have pressed, drink Soma, O thou Soma's Lord,
>      Indra best Vṛtra-slayer Strong One, with the Strong.
> 2. Strong is the stone, the draught is strong, strong is this Soma that is pressed,
>      Indra, best Vṛtra-slayer, Strong One with the Strong.
> 3. As strong I call on thee the Strong, O Thunder-armed, with various aids,
>      Indra, best Vṛtra-slayer, Strong One with the Strong.
> 4. Impetuous, Thunderer, Strong, quelling the mighty, King, potent, Vṛtra-slayer, Soma-drinker,
>      May he come hither with his yoked Bay Horses; may Indra gladden him at the noon libation.
> 5. O Sūrya, when the Asura's descendant Svarbhanu, pierced thee through and through with darkness,
>      All creatures looked like one who is bewildered, who knoweth not the place where he is standing.
> 6. What time thou smotest down Svarbhanu's magic that spread itself beneath the sky, O Indra,
>      By his fourth sacred prayer Atri discovered Sūrya concealed in gloom that stayed his function.
> 7. Let not the oppressor with this dread, through anger swallow me up, for I am thine, O Atri.
>      Mitra art thou, the sender of true blessings: thou and King Varuṇa be both my helpers.
> 8. The Brahman Atri, as he set the press-stones, serving the Gods with praise and adoration,
>      Established in the heaven the eye of Sūrya, and caused Svarbhanu's magic arts to vanish.
> 9. The Atris found the Sun again, him whom Svarbhanu of the brood
>      Of Asuras had pierced with gloom. This none besides had power to do.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the original Shlokas too. This English is so weird to read but something is better than nothing. :)

Comment: The sacred-text site has screwed up the word Svarbanu in the Shloka.

Comment: Also, you need to work on your formatting :)

Comment: yes, I have already started :)